# Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before bool

Tags: c++, c

I wrote in C function:

```
    void func(int count,bool infini){
//...
}
```

I try compile this code with Code Blocks, (GCC) spike:

> "expected declaration specifiers or '...' before bool"

.
Where is bug?

Comment: `bool` is not a keyword in the C language. It is defined in the header `<stdbool.h>` (C99) which you failed to include. You can use the C99 keyword `_Bool` if you don't want to include the header.

Comment: @pmg Should have posted that as an answer :-)

Comment: @cnicutar: I don't know C++ enough to write an answer that encompasses the two languages. A comment is good enough for me :)

Comment: @pmg: `bool` *is* a keyword in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are that you are compiling in C mode. C does not have `bool`. Use `int` instead or include `stdbool.h` to get a `#define` of `bool` (only C99) or create a typedef / `#define` yourself (if your compiler doesn't have or you don't want to use `stdbool.h`. But GCC provides this header).

Alternatively in C99 code you can use `_Bool` instead (which is a keyword in C99, much like `bool` is to C++), but take in mind that C99 is not widely supported.

Comment: `_Bool` is probably exactly as portable as `<stdbool.h>`.

Answer (score -4):

The `bool` is in C++ but not in C.

Comment: it is not in C89 or C90, but it is in C99, which is also C

Comment: @AliVeli: `bool` is in C99 (and C11), but only as a macro in `<stdbool.h>`; `_Bool` is the corresponding keyword.